# Display only the first item of object array

Tags: angular

I have an array that i want to display from it the first item in a span .

At the moment i'm getting all the value instead of only the first one.

```
  <div class="card">  
    <div *ngIf="selectedUser._id">
      <div class="user" *ngFor="let user of users">
             <span>  {{ user.event }} </span>
            </div>
  </div>
  </div>
```

It's returning me the list of all users date event, i only want the first one

I also tried to add user.event[0] not working it's displaying me the first char of the date

my array of object

```
[{id:XYZ, event:Fri Jul 20 2018 15:00:04 GMT+0200 (CEST)},{id:XYZ1, name:Fri Jul 10 2018 15:00:04 GMT+0200 (CEST)},{id:XYZ2, name:Fri Aug 20 2018 15:00:04 GMT+0200 (CEST)}]
```

Comment: where is the date? can use post the structure of users?

Answer (score 1):

Use the simple approch below,

```
<div class="card">  
    <div *ngIf="selectedUser._id">
      <div class="user">
         <span>  {{ users[0].event }} </span>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is the most simple working solution to this as I think

Comment: unfortunately tried this i get TypeError: Cannot read property 'date' of undefined

Answer (score 0):

you can use `slice` pipe.

```
<div class="user" *ngFor="let user of users | slice:0:1;">
    <span>  {{ user.event }} </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="card">
  <div>
    <div class="user">
      <div>{{users[0]}}</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer.  Please explain your answer and how it solves the problem in the question.

Answer (score 0):

You dont need

```
<div class="card">  
    <div>
      <div class="user">
             <span>    {{ users[0].event | date:'medium' }} </span>
     </div>
</div>
```

**[STACKBLITZ DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ym1g6h?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)**